# Android - Two spinners in one Activity - Saving Data is not working

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

my problem is the following. I have 2 Spinners in one activity. I want that both spinner items should be saved in the DB. But there is a slight difference between both spinners:

- Spinner 1: Is populated by data from other db-table - when it is the only spinner in the mentioned activity, it works.
- Spinner 2: Has default values. I am not sure if added it correctly to my activity. Anyway, after i added it to my saving the data is not working anymore.

Please help me what am I doing wrong??

My Activity Code:

```
public class activity_transport extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    Button btn_save;
    Spinner ChooseProject,ChooseTransport;
    EditText Entfernung,Price,MWST;
    String selectedspinner, selectedTransport;

    ImageView imageView2;
    private static int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    Uri imageUri;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transport);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        ChooseProject = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ChooseProject);
        ChooseTransport = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ChooseTransport);
        Entfernung = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Entfernung);
        Price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Preis);
        MWST = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MwSt);
        btn_save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        //bildanzeigebereich im layout
        imageView2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        loadProjectSpinnerData();
        //loadTransportSpinnerData();
        SaveData();

    //+++++++++++++++Function to load the spinner data from SQLite database++++++++++//

    private void loadProjectSpinnerData() {
        // database handler
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper (getApplicationContext());

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> projects = db.getAllProjects();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, projects);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ChooseProject.setPrompt("Projekt auswählen");

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        ChooseProject.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



        //Choose Transport Spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {
                new String("Auto"),
                new String("Flugzeug"),
                new String("Taxi"),
                new String("Bahn")});
        ChooseTransport.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ChooseTransport.setPrompt("Transport auswählen");

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        ChooseTransport.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


        //Listener für den Projekt Spinner damit ich den Wert abspeichern kann
        ChooseProject.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
                if(spinner.getId() == R.id.ChooseProject)
                {
                    selectedspinner = (String) ChooseProject.getSelectedItem();
                }
                else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.ChooseTransport)
                {
                    selectedTransport = (String) ChooseTransport.getSelectedItem();
                }
                //selectedspinner =String.ValueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));

            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }






    /*private void loadTransportSpinnerData() {
        // Spinner method to read the on selected value
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {
                new String("Auto"),
                new String("Flugzeug"),
                new String("Taxi"),
                new String("Bahn")});
        ChooseTransport.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


        // Creating adapter for spinner
        //ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, projects);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ChooseTransport.setPrompt("Transport auswählen");

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        ChooseTransport.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        //Listener für den Projekt Spinner damit ich den Wert abspeichern kann
        ChooseTransport.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                //selectedspinner =String.ValueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));
                selectedTransport = (String) ChooseTransport.getSelectedItem();
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

    }*/



    //++++++++++++Save Data++++++//
    public void SaveData(){
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isInserted = myDb.createTransport(
                                selectedspinner,
                                selectedTransport,
                                Integer.valueOf(Price.getText().toString()),
                                Integer.valueOf(MWST.getText().toString()),
                                Integer.valueOf(Entfernung.getText().toString()),
                                imageViewToByte(imageView2)
                        );
                        if(isInserted=true)
                            Toast.makeText(activity_transport.this, "Daten gespeichert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(activity_transport.this, "Daten nicht gespeichert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
        );
    }


}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to run the app by setting a few breakpoints. 
When trying to run this line `selectedTransport = (String) ChooseTransport.getSelectedItem();` the debugger posts `Cannot find local variable 'ChooseTransport'`

Comment: what do you mean by "saving data is not working anymore"? what is your question?

Comment: saving the data in my database is not working.. my question is what I am doing by implementing the spinner 2?

Comment: in my code spinner 2 is `ChooseTransport`

Comment: You've given a massive code dump with little or no explanation.  Did you try stepping through the activity with breakpoints to see what is happening?  If your code is broken, it's broken for a reason, and _you_ should be giving _us_ hints about the problem, not vice-versa.

Comment: I did not try to step with breakpoints through code..
My assumption is that the second spinner `ChooseTransport` is not working properly, since I have the same class twice with the same code only the mentioned spinner is missing.

Comment: Now I shortened my code a little bit, i hope it's helpful. I have one method `loadProjectSpinnerData()`where I  populate spinner 1 with data from DB and where I set Spinner 1 & 2 to the adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

I implemented an own method for `ChooseTransport`- Spinner and now it works. I also figured out that the order how I add the data to the DB was not right. I changed this too.

See here my method for my second spinner:

```
private void loadTransportSpinnerData(){


        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.transport, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ChooseTransport.setPrompt("Transport auswählen");
        ChooseTransport.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        ChooseTransport.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                selectedTransport = (String) ChooseTransport.getSelectedItem();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

    }
```